# Jade engine in express.js does not warn or throw error for missing commas

Tags: java, node.js, express, pug

I'm using jade as view engine in my node/express app, and it works just fine, even more too fine :) It does not throw error or warning if a comma is missing between tag attributes. For example:

```
div.main(data-ng-controller="ctrl" data-ng-form="form")
```

or

```
script(type="text/javascript" src="script.js" charset="utf-8")
```

compiles without errors, however the jade syntax docs says to use commas or new lines to separate tag attributes, so these should be the correct lines:

```
div.main(data-ng-controller="ctrl", data-ng-form="form")
script(type="text/javascript", src="script.js", charset="utf-8")
```

And the problem is that I use the same jade templates also in a java project, and the java-jade compiler throws bad syntax exception because the missing attribute separators.

In my opinion the node-jade compiler has a bug or something, and the java-jade compiler works in the righ way: as it should. The inconvenience is if I miss a comma during developing my pages in node environment, I won't notice the error until building my java project.

Is it possible to set up the node-jade compiler to throw errors or warnings for missing commas, or am I using it wrong?

The express setup is like this:

```
app.set('views', 'path/to/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: What you say is a bug is a stated feature in the docs: http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes